# itunes equalizer per track settings

Tags: itunes

I'm a little confused about iTune's ability to set eq presets on a per-song basis.

I have a song that I open, set to a given EQ preset, then close.

When I play this song, however, the audio isn't being adjusted.

If I open the EQ and turn it 'on', though, it then obeys the song's eq setting.

Of course, if I leave the EQ on, then songs that do not have their own EQ setting default to whatever the EQ was originally set at.

Not a HUGE deal, but it means that I would then normally have to have EQ always turned on, set to flat, so that any song that I HAVE given a EQ setting to will use it.

Am I understanding how that works correctly? Is there a way to have individual songs use their EQ setting without having to turn on the EQ for everything?